# Call external exe multiple times one after another

Tags: java, exe

I am calling an external exe using the following commands:

```
String bat_file = "cmd /c start out.bat";
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(bat_file);
```

The problem is that I need to call the specific exe multiple times but one after another(the next exe starts after the previous exe is finished). They can not run simultaneously as they access the same files.

I tried to use a for but is not working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your approach is basically the *start* command. It creates a separate process. If you remove it, you can successfully use *waitFor*:

```
String batchFile = "cmd /c out.bat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batchFile);
int resultCode = p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you. I finally solved it using

```
String batchFile = "cmd /c start/wait out.bat";
```